# Can't initialize a new URL with Pafy/youtube_dl, I am getting "ERROR: This video is unavailable"

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl, pafy

I'm trying to stream select videos from youtube using pafy (0.5.4) and youtube_dl, but am now getting an unavailable error no matter what url I use.

My code was working a few weeks ago, but when I tried it today I was getting a HTTP is not supported error.  As a result I upgraded youtube_dl to 20190901 and now I am getting a source unavailable error despite being able to play the youtube link in my browser.

```py
import pafy
import youtube_dl
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qvXvDfGnh8&ab_channel=ChannelTD'
vPafy = pafy.new(url)
```

This should initalize the pafy object, but instead returns the following error:

"ERROR: This video is unavailable."

Comment: As of today, September 11, 2019, `youtube-dl 2019.09.01` is not working with youtube.

Comment: with ```youtube-dl 2019.09.12``` it's back up and running.

Answer (score 0):

The response to Youtube service requests changed recently. After installing youtube-dl from the master https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl, my scripts resumed functioning.

Comment: It's important to update youtube-dl either regularly or at least if an error occurs! P.S.: it can be updated by executing `youtube-dl -U`!